# Can a schedule be conflict serializable but not serializable?

Tags: concurrency, scheduling, database-theory, process-scheduling

A schedule is called conflict serializable if it can be transformed into a serial schedule by swapping non-conflicting operations. Then, 
My question is: Can a schedule be conflict serializable but not serializable? 
Please explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. As you can see in the following picture, conflict serializable schedules are a subset of serializable schedules, therefore all of them are serializable.

[image: schedules]